# Bookmarkable URL with search parameters?

Tags: angularjs

I have some search functionality in my page, which uses GET requests and a JSON backend.

I want that if I run a search, I get an URL in the browser, with all the parameters, which the user can bookmark.

Let's say my search is:

```
search?key=a
```

I put this code in the success callback of the search, to update the URL:

```
$location.path("/search?key=a");
```

But then my URL gets updated to:

```
search#/search%3Fkey=a
```

If the user bookmarks this, of course it will not run the search, it will just show the search page with a blank input field.

I already did the setup to show the search results when the user has the correct link - I added this to the controller:

```
if (location.search) {
    $scope.callMyApi(location.search);
}
```

But when I'm using the links I get from AngularJS, like `search#/search%3Fkey=a`, `$location.search()` is empty.

`$location.path()`, on the other hand, has what I need:

```
/search?key=a
```

I could split this, and get the search string, and pass it to `callMyApi`. But it feels like I'm missing the Angular way to do it.

Already read the doc about [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) and some articles about routing, but still don't know what I have to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the location `path` method with `search` method. Something like

```
$location.path('/search').search({key:'a'});
```

Can you check documentation on how to use $location in [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location).

Comment: Uhm yes I wrote that I read the documentation already,the question is more like is this the Angular/correct way to do it? Also I have many search parameters, would have to loop through them or something... feels a bit messy.

Comment: I think this is the only way. You need to pass a js object, so if you have multiple parameters create a js object and pass it to search.